# I use this Javascript code, it does the job, but I feel it could be shorter

Tags: javascript, html

I use this function to to do some calculations based on 4 select inputs and one number input, I dont have experience in Js, I did some research in w3schools then I ended up with the function bellow.
The Js function is working exactly as I want, but I feel it is not the perfect syntax and it could be shorter and somehow cleaner, any advice would be appreciated.

```js
function calculate() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Lang_from").value);
  var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Lang_to").value);
  var q = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
  var s = parseFloat(document.getElementById("subject").value);
  var f = parseFloat(document.getElementById("file_type").value);
  var xx = document.getElementById('Lang_from').selectedOptions[0].text;
  var yy = document.getElementById('Lang_to').selectedOptions[0].text;
  var ff = document.getElementById('file_type').selectedOptions[0].text;
  var ss = document.getElementById('subject').selectedOptions[0].text;

  document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = (x + y) * q + (s + f);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<html>

<body>

  <div class="pricing_row">
    <div class="pricing_column">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h4 class="pricing_lable">From</h4>
        <select id="Lang_from" name="Lang_from" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
          <option id="en2ar" value="0.025">English</option>
          <option>German</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <h4 class="pricing_lable">To</h4>
        <select id="Lang_to" name="Lang_to" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
          <option value="0.025">German</option>
          <option>English</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing_column">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h4 class="pricing_lable">File type</h4>
        <select id="file_type" name="file_type" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
          <option value="0">TXT</option>
          <option value="3">MS word</option>
          <option value="5">PDF (+5$)</option>
          <option value="10">Hand Writing</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <h4 class="pricing_lable">Subject</h4>
        <select id="subject" name="subject" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
          <option value="0">General</option>
          <option value="10">Technical / IT</option>
          <option value="15">Medical</option>
          <option value="5">Press</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing_column">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h4 class="pricing_lable">Word count</h4>
        <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="500" value="1000" class="form-control pricing_input pricing_input_number">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button id="calculate" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pricing_btn_calc" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

        <div id="total_price"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are not using the variables `xx`, `yy`, `ff` and `ss`. Why are you declaring them?

Comment: What is purpose of variables xx,yy,ff and ss ?

Comment: If I were you I would post this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This will lead you to different libraries or js frameworks of your flavor. As of the current implementation there is nothing wrong with this despite the lengthy code. Trust me this is much easier to read, easier to modify, a.k.a maintainable and readable. What I recommend is you keep your variable names self descriptive rather than using which would seem random characters. Especially x, y and z are more of applicable for coordinates, i, j for looping indeces. You'll see what I mean with the coming different answers.

Comment: @Mark_Ed Nice idea, I joined that community, thank you.

Comment: @ColdCerberus Happy to hear this, I will consider your advices, thank you.

Comment: @GokulRajK.N. I use them in the original page.

Comment: @CristianTraìna I use them in the original page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about how to improve working code belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Quentin I had no idea about that community!

Comment: @adiga Many thanks for cleaning out the code :)

Comment: @Quentin Please don't close questions because of the existence of another site that _may_ be able to answer the posted question. Given that you have pretty much no rep on Code Review, I don't think you're an authority on what is or is not on-topic there. Please don't close questions on Stack Overflow because you think, but don't know, it's on-topic for another site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be to define a local helper function that returns a floating point number from a field element by `id` like this:

```
function floatFrom(id) {
   return Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value); 
}
```

Using the `floatFrom()` helper, you could then shorten your `calculate()` function to this:

```
function calculate() {

    function floatFrom(id) {
       return Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value); 
    }

    document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = 
        (floatFrom("Lang_from") + floatFrom("Lang_to")) * floatFrom("quantity") + 
        (floatFrom("subject") + floatFrom("file_type"));
}
```

Note also that `xx`, `yy`, `ff` and `ss` appear to be redundant and can also be removed from `calcuate()` to simplify the function.

For a working example please see the snippet below:

```js
function calculate() {

  function floatFrom(id) {
    return Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value);
  }

  document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML =
    (floatFrom("Lang_from") + floatFrom("Lang_to")) * floatFrom("quantity") +
    (floatFrom("subject") + floatFrom("file_type"));
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing_row">
  <div class="pricing_column">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">From</h4>
      <select id="Lang_from" name="Lang_from" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
        <option id="en2ar" value="0.025">English</option>
        <!-- added value -->
        <option value="0.75">German</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">To</h4>
      <select id="Lang_to" name="Lang_to" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
        <option value="0.025">German</option>
        <!-- added value -->
        <option value="0.75">English</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pricing_column">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">File type</h4>
      <select id="file_type" name="file_type" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
        <option value="0">TXT</option>
        <option value="3">MS word</option>
        <option value="5">PDF (+5$)</option>
        <option value="10">Hand Writing</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">Subject</h4>
      <select id="subject" name="subject" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
        <option value="0">General</option>
        <option value="10">Technical / IT</option>
        <option value="15">Medical</option>
        <option value="5">Press</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pricing_column">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">Word count</h4>
      <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="500" value="1000" class="form-control pricing_input pricing_input_number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="calculate" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pricing_btn_calc" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

      <div id="total_price"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you learn more on your JS journey, you will encounter more problems like this which will lead you to various flavors of frameworks and libraries of your taste. (Hence you're having a taste of plain "vanilla js" for now) Each may have their pros and cons, syntax wise, design as a whole, etc. Now as an example, your desire might be to eliminate the lengthy individual variable definition. You may have something like this (though there are many ways to deal with it):

```
const fields = ['Lang_from', 'Lang_to', 'quantity', 'subject', 'file_type'];
var values = [];

function get(field) {
  var i = fields.indexOf(field);
  return values[i];
}

function getValues() {
  values = fields.map(field => 
    { 
      return parseFloat(document.getElementById(field).value || 0) 
    });
}

function calculate(field) {
  getValues(); // gets all the values from defined fields
  document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = 
    (get('Lang_from') + get('Lang_to')) * get('quantity') + (get('subject') + get('file_type'));
}
```

Then you may end up scratching your head with the redundant `get` calls. In general, you'll deal with this always. My suggestion is you keep your code as is and perhaps improve your **variable naming to be self descriptive**. Just keep in mind to **target making a highly readable and maintainable code** and **do not overly abstract** your code for the sole purpose of having a fewer lines of code.

**But wait!..**

You actually don't need the `get` method!

with [ES6 Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
function calculate(field) {
  getValues(); // gets all the values from defined fields
  var [x, y, q, s, f] = values;
  document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = (x + y) * q + (s + f);
}
```

Comment: For your ES6 version to work, you need an additional `return` ind `getValues` function

Comment: @yunzen, Thanks for pointing that out, the variable `values` in this case is global, found outside the calculate function. Is this still not gonna work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can remove your duplicate selectors like:

```
document.getElementById("Lang_from")
```

You can make a variable with the selector in it.

```
var lang_form = document.getElementById("Lang_from");
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer, congratulations on starting your JavaScript journey. It's a fun (though bumpy) road to be on.

In my experience, there are always at least 2 ways to do something in JavaScript. In the end, it's not so much about **how** you write it but rather **how you understand it after a while**. That said, there are a few **recommendations** you can follow.

With your code, I would recommend you not use a lot of IDs because it complicates things fast.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code regarding the length. JavaScript is a somwhat lenghty language, especially if you use the DOM methods like `getElementById`

If I were you I'd do something like this

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

// encaspulate your functions in an anonymous function, so the global namespace doesn't get polluted and you don't conflict with other JS code

;(function() {
  // make an accessor function for the values
  function get_value(id, number) {
    if (number) {
      return parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value);
    } else {
      return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
  }
  
  // make an output function
  function output(value) {
    document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = parseInt(Math.round(value * 100)) / 100
  }
  
  function calculate() {
    var x = get_value("Lang_from", true);
    var y = get_value("Lang_to", true);
    var q = get_value("quantity", true);
    var s = get_value("subject", true);
    var f = get_value("file_type", true);

    output((x + y) * q + (s + f));
  }
  
  function listen(id, event, func) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, func);  
  }
  
  // don't use the `onclick` attribute handler on the HTML element, but listen to events with JavaScript
  listen('calculate', 'click', calculate);
  
  // Listen to change events on the selects. This way the output updates after every 
  listen('Lang_from', 'input', calculate);
  listen('Lang_to', 'input', calculate);
  listen('quantity', 'input', calculate);
  listen('subject', 'input', calculate);
  listen('file_type', 'input', calculate);

  // calculate on load, so the output gets preoccupied
  calculate()  
  
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="pricing_row">
  <div class="pricing_column">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">From</h4>
      <select id="Lang_from" name="Lang_from" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
          <option id="en2ar" value="0.025">English</option>
          <option value="0.025">German</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">To</h4>
      <select id="Lang_to" name="Lang_to" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
          <option value="0.025">German</option>
          <option value="0.025">English</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pricing_column">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">File type</h4>
      <select id="file_type" name="file_type" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
          <option value="0">TXT</option>
          <option value="3">MS word</option>
          <option value="5">PDF (+5$)</option>
          <option value="10">Hand Writing</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">Subject</h4>
      <select id="subject" name="subject" value="" class="form-control pricing_input">
          <option value="0">General</option>
          <option value="10">Technical / IT</option>
          <option value="15">Medical</option>
          <option value="5">Press</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pricing_column">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 class="pricing_lable">Word count</h4>
      <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="500" value="1000" class="form-control pricing_input pricing_input_number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="calculate" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pricing_btn_calc">Calculate</button>

      <div id="total_price"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think my function is simpler... though I can learn from your function anyway, thank you :)